# jsonObjectRequest error message is null

Tags: php, android, mysql, xampp

So I'm working on an android application that retrieves data from a MySQL database on a xampp server. Here is the code from the android main,

```
Button scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
String findUrl = "http://myIPaddress/webservice/findItem.php";
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
scanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectrequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
        findUrl, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
                try{
                    //retrieve the items table from the database
                    JSONArray items = response.getJSONArray("items");
                    int i = 2;
                    //retrieve the 3rd row in the table
                    JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = item.getString("name");
                    //send a LogCat message containing the name of the row                  
                    Log.d("name",name); 
                } catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                //in case of an error, send a logcat message containing the error
                Log.d("error","" + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectrequest);
    }
});

}
```

The php scripts are in a webservice folder, which is in the htdocs folder of the xampp folder. Here is the script for connection.php (declares and sets up the connection for the database),

```
<?php

define('hostname', 'localhost');
define('user','root');
define('password','');
define('databaseName','webservice');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname, user, password, databaseName);

?>
```

and the script for findItem.php (returns the "items" table from the "webservice" database in my local host phpmyadmin),

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){
    include 'connection.php';
    showItem();
}

function showItem(){
    global $connect;

    $query = "Select * FROM ITEMS";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    $number_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    $temp_array = array();

    if($number_of_rows > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $temp_array[] = $row;
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array("items"=>$temp_array));
    mysqli_close($connect);
}

?>
```

The error I am encountering occurs at run time. When I click the button in my android emulator, the logcat message is not the name from the 3rd row of the "items" table. There is an error message, but the error ends up being null. My question is basically what could possibly be causing this? I have made sure that the php scripts were in the right location(xampp/htdocs/webservice), the ip address is correct, the xampp servers for apache and mysql are on, the right permissions were written in the android manifest file, and an "items" table with at least 3 rows existed in a database called "webservice". Any feedback is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So although I didn't receive any answers on this question, I was able to figure out what was wrong. First, I checked if the database even existed by using the postman app (google chrome extension) since I used post methods in the php scripts. The database did in fact exist. Therefore, the problem was most likely the ip address despite my incorrect assumption in the question. The ip address I originally had in the findUrl string was correct, but still wrong. It was a valid ip address, but the database is on a locally hosted server; therefore, the ip address was supposed to be the local ip address. For some reason, the ip address I was using was not the local one, so that was the fix. If anyone was wondering how I found the local ip address on Windows, just run command prompt and type "ipconfig". The local ip address should be by "ipv4 address".